# How to limit width of anchor element to width of his child elements (h1 and h2)

Tags: html, css

Ok i have div with id "logo" inside div i have h1 and h2 element and i have problem to anchor them... If i put anchor inside h1 or h2 width is same as text width but i have space between h1 and h2 which not belong to link..

If i wrap h1 and h2 inside of achor its ok but width take full width of header element (parent of all elements i mentioned)

I also tried to put h1 and h2 inside of anchor element (without using div) but it took full width of header (i used display block, not working)

Comment: Please show the markup and CSS for the effort you've made.

Comment: My guess is that you need to make your headings inline-block.

Comment: can you make a fiddle(on http://jsfiddle.net/) of your code..???

Comment: <header>
<a href="index.html" id="logo">
 <h1>Some text</h1>
 <h2>Some text</h2>
</a>
</header>

I have navigation also inaside header but thats working fine so no need to post it here..

As for CSS

 header {
  background-color: #6ab47b;
  color: #fff;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 0 30px 0;
  padding: 5px 0 0 0;
  width: 100%;
 }

and #logo

 #logo {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  background-color: orange;
 }

h1 and h2 are styled only for font size, weight (and h2 margin -5px so it is closer to h1 which is on top)

Answer (score 0):

Try this fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4zbnLgzk/)

In this fiddle just added

```
.header{
     text-align: center;
  } 

#logo{
    display: inline-block;
  }
```

Comment: Thank you, my #logo was display block and i thought adding inline wont change anything.. And text align center in header forced logo in middle of header.. Thank you very much...

Comment: Please mark it as correct if it's an answer what you needed.